# datetimepicker in visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I have a problem in my C# code.

```
string searchstring = " and UsersStartDate Between '" + String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}",
        Convert.ToDateTime(calender_from.Text))
    + "' And'" + String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}",
              Convert.ToDateTime(calender_till.Text))+ "'";
```

I wrote this code for the datepicker, and I set display set 1/1/2015, I have an error in run time. `"System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime'`. I am following a training C# video and the guy in the video has answer I have this error.

Comment: Could you try setting a specific `DateTimeFormatInfo` in 2nd parameter of Convert.ToDateTime()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string is `1/1/2015`, so this is day/month/year or month/day/year (no leading zeros).

But your format string is `yyyy/MM/dd` which is year/month/day (with leading zeros).

Use the correct format string that matches your input. For `1/1/2015` it might be `M/d/yyyy` or `d/M/yyyy`. You can pass this format to [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx).

See [Custom DateTime Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
using System.Globalization;

string dateString = "1/1/2015";
string format = "d/M/yyyy";
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```